# Postgresql: multicolumn indexes vs single column index

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I have a table that will grow by 10M of rows every year.

The table has 10 columns, call them c1, c2, c3, ..., c10.

I will use the `WHERE` clause, potentially on 8 of them.

To be more specific: every time I will query the table, there will **always** be a `WHERE` clause on column c10 (it's a date, I could search for equality or range).

The other 7 possible searchable columns, will not follow any schema.
I could search for:

- c10, c1, c2, c5
- c10, c5
- c10, c3
- c10, c2, c6
- c10, c2, c3, c5, c6

... and all other possible combinations.

So, in a `WHERE` clause, c10 will always be present and the others could be present in any combination (even not present at all).

**What indexing strategy could improve performance in this scenario?
I think that the right thing to do, is to create a single index for every column. There could be any performance improvements using a multicolumn index?**

From what I know, you will gain performance with a multicolumn index on (c1, c2, c3), only for queries that use c1, c2, c3 or c1, c2, or c1, in this order. But like I said, the only thing I can assume in my scenario, is that c10 will always be present in a WHERE clause (it can also be the first clause, if this helps)

Comment: Postgres is pretty efficient in combining multiple indexes in a single query. So you definitely want one on  `c10` - the others totally depend on your query. If the condition on `c10` already reduces the number of rows substantially additional indexes might not help further. Without seeing the real queries, the real table definition and the execution plans with real world data this is hard to tell

Comment: in the best scenario, the condition on c10 will reduce the number of rows in 100k. I believe that 100k+ rows will require additional indexes in query where c10 isn't the only clause

Comment: Does the table have a primary key / do any of the {cx,cy,...} sets constitute  candidate keys? Are the cx columns all truly independent? What are the cardinalities of the cx columns, and their combinations?

Comment: the primary key is a simple autoincrement id. No set constitutes candidate keys. The cardinality of cx columns (if you mean columns used in where clause) start from 1 to 8.

Answer (score 19):

To answer the question of what kind of index should we use, we can create a simple test. first, we create a database, table, and index.

```
CREATE DATABASE index_test;

CREATE TABLE single_column(a int, b int, c int);
CREATE TABLE multi_column(a int, b int, c int);

CREATE INDEX single_column_a_idx ON single_column (a);
CREATE INDEX single_column_b_idx ON single_column (b);
CREATE INDEX single_column_c_idx ON single_column (c);

CREATE INDEX multi_column_idx ON multi_column (a, b, c);
```

populate the table with random data.

```
-- this function will be used for random number generation
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION random_in_range(INTEGER, INTEGER) RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
SELECT floor(($1 + ($2 - $1 + 1) * random()))::INTEGER;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;

INSERT INTO single_column(a, b, c)
SELECT random_in_range(1, 100),
    random_in_range(1, 100),
    random_in_range(1, 100)
FROM generate_series(1, 1000000);

INSERT INTO multi_column(a, b, c)
SELECT random_in_range(1, 100),
    random_in_range(1, 100),
    random_in_range(1, 100)
FROM generate_series(1, 1000000);
```

run the test.

```sql
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM single_column WHERE a < 3;
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM single_column WHERE b < 3;
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM single_column WHERE c < 3;

EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM multi_column WHERE a < 3;
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM multi_column WHERE b < 3;
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM multi_column WHERE c < 3;

EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM single_column WHERE a < 3 AND b > 10 AND c <= 11;
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM multi_column WHERE a < 3 AND b > 10 AND c <= 11;
```

result

```sql
index_test=# EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM single_column WHERE a < 3;
                                                               QUERY PLAN                                               
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on single_column  (cost=3925.39..13926.49 rows=367608 width=12) (actual time=5.802..44.904 rows=20070 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: (a < 3)
   Heap Blocks: exact=5269
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on single_column_a_idx  (cost=0.00..3833.49 rows=367608 width=0) (actual time=4.018..4.019 rows=20070 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (a < 3)
 Planning Time: 0.325 ms
 Execution Time: 46.589 ms
(7 rows)


index_test=# EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM single_column WHERE b < 3;
                                                               QUERY PLAN                                               
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on single_column  (cost=3925.39..13926.49 rows=367608 width=12) (actual time=6.630..26.814 rows=19902 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: (b < 3)
   Heap Blocks: exact=5296
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on single_column_b_idx  (cost=0.00..3833.49 rows=367608 width=0) (actual time=4.852..4.853 rows=19902 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (b < 3)
 Planning Time: 0.270 ms
 Execution Time: 28.762 ms
(7 rows)


index_test=# EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM single_column WHERE c < 3;
                                                               QUERY PLAN                                               
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on single_column  (cost=3925.39..13926.49 rows=367608 width=12) (actual time=5.896..25.304 rows=19946 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: (c < 3)
   Heap Blocks: exact=5274
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on single_column_c_idx  (cost=0.00..3833.49 rows=367608 width=0) (actual time=4.125..4.126 rows=19946 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (c < 3)
 Planning Time: 0.270 ms
 Execution Time: 27.136 ms
(7 rows)


index_test=# EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM multi_column WHERE a < 3;
                                                             QUERY PLAN                                                 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on multi_column  (cost=8569.39..18570.49 rows=367608 width=12) (actual time=7.760..67.173 rows=19938 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: (a < 3)
   Heap Blocks: exact=5267
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on multi_column_idx  (cost=0.00..8477.49 rows=367608 width=0) (actual time=6.008..6.008 rows=19938 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (a < 3)
 Planning Time: 0.564 ms
 Execution Time: 68.630 ms
(7 rows)


index_test=# EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM multi_column WHERE b < 3;
                                                           QUERY PLAN                                                   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Gather  (cost=1000.00..13481.03 rows=18667 width=12) (actual time=1.451..135.028 rows=19897 loops=1)
   Workers Planned: 2
   Workers Launched: 2
   ->  Parallel Seq Scan on multi_column  (cost=0.00..10614.33 rows=7778 width=12) (actual time=0.038..61.993 rows=6632 loops=3)
         Filter: (b < 3)
         Rows Removed by Filter: 326701
 Planning Time: 1.123 ms
 Execution Time: 136.128 ms
(8 rows)


index_test=# EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM multi_column WHERE c < 3;
                                                           QUERY PLAN                                                   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Gather  (cost=1000.00..13627.63 rows=20133 width=12) (actual time=0.957..135.119 rows=19860 loops=1)
   Workers Planned: 2
   Workers Launched: 2
   ->  Parallel Seq Scan on multi_column  (cost=0.00..10614.33 rows=8389 width=12) (actual time=0.035..66.760 rows=6620 loops=3)
         Filter: (c < 3)
         Rows Removed by Filter: 326713
 Planning Time: 0.225 ms
 Execution Time: 136.239 ms
(8 rows)


index_test=# EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM single_column WHERE a < 3 AND b > 10 AND c <= 11;
                                                                   QUERY PLAN                                           
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on single_column  (cost=1424.66..5716.83 rows=2110 width=12) (actual time=21.694..26.123 rows=2000 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: ((a < 3) AND (c <= 11))
   Filter: (b > 10)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 230
   Heap Blocks: exact=1833
   ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=1424.66..1424.66 rows=2338 width=0) (actual time=20.981..20.983 rows=0 loops=1)
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on single_column_a_idx  (cost=0.00..230.43 rows=21067 width=0) (actual time=3.932..3.932 rows=20070 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (a < 3)
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on single_column_c_idx  (cost=0.00..1192.92 rows=111000 width=0) (actual time=16.080..16.080 rows=110276 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (c <= 11)
 Planning Time: 1.812 ms
 Execution Time: 26.742 ms
(12 rows)


index_test=# EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM multi_column WHERE a < 3 AND b > 10 AND c <= 11;
                                                                 QUERY PLAN                                             
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Only Scan using multi_column_idx on multi_column  (cost=0.42..642.38 rows=2071 width=12) (actual time=0.329..2.086 rows=1953 loops=1)
   Index Cond: ((a < 3) AND (b > 10) AND (c <= 11))
   Heap Fetches: 0
 Planning Time: 0.176 ms
 Execution Time: 2.165 ms
(5 rows)
```

### Conclusion

- `single_column` table will always use the index in any condition.

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM single_column WHERE a < 3; -- index used
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM single_column WHERE b < 3; -- index used
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM single_column WHERE c < 3; -- index used

EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM single_column WHERE a < 3 AND b > 10 AND c <= 11; -- index used
```

- Single column WHERE performed on `multi_column` table, the index will only be used if the column in the query is the same as the first column in the index definition.

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM multi_column WHERE a < 3; -- index used
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM multi_column WHERE b < 3; -- index not used
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM multi_column WHERE c < 3; -- index not used
```

- Although `single_column` table can use indexes on multi column WHERE, `multi_column` table is faster.
- Although `multi_column` table can use indexes on single column WHERE, `single_column` table is faster.

Answer (score 4):

Multi-column indexes are very versatile, more versatile than single column indexes.  A multi-column index on `(c1, c2)` also works for queries where an index on `(c1)` would work.

Assuming your conditions are all equality conditions, then the order of the columns in the index doesn't matter.  For the conditions that you describe, the following indexes will optimize fully all queries:

- `(c10, c5, c1, c2)`
- `(c10, c3)`
- `(c10, c2, c6)`
- `(c10, c2, d3, c5, c6)`

Whether you need all these indexes is a different matter.  That depends on how selective the columns are (that is, what proportion of rows in the table they are choosing).  Filtering a few dozen rows by retrieving the values is not particularly expensive.  So, if the `c10` condition returns just a handful of rows, then including the other columns in the index may not be a significant additional performance improvement.

In addition, more indexes mean that inserts, updates, and deletes take more time.  That can also affect your indexing strategy.

Partitioning (as mentioned in another answer) is also useful.  Whether it is appropriate for your situation, depends on what the data and queries look like.

Comment: my clause examples were incomplete. I could perform queries with a clause that is c10 (range) potentially followed by every column in every order

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest the following strategy:

- Creating single column indexes on the other columns;
- Partitioning on `c10`. As it is a date, you can partition by range, making yearly or monthly partitions.

I've seen huge performance increases with partitioning, specially in cases where one or more columns are always used in `WHERE`, and large tables.